# Need to show() or remove() an element depending on who's logged in

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.nlgchat').hide(); // or do it with CSS...

      var usernames = ['Mr.EasyBB','runawayhorses','BL@DE','SirChivas'];

 var nameslist='';
 $('ul li a.mainmenu').each(function( i ){ 
var name = $(this).text().split(' ')[3];
nameslist += '||'+name; // ||dana||roko||john
 });

 for(i=0;i<usernames.length;i++){
 if( nameslist.indexOf( '||'+usernames[i] ) > -1 ){
    $('.nlgchat').show();
    return;
 }else{
    $('.nlgchat').remove();
    return;    
  }
}

 });
})(jQuery);
```

I use this code to make it so only some people can see the `.nlgchat` but the code only works for my name and not anyone else's in the list.

I want the users listed above to be able to see it, everyone else `.remove`

http://jsfiddle.net/z62Pf/

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net to help out here. Without seeing an example its is almost impossible to help you out. Also, this is not a secure way of hiding content at all.

Comment: yeah I know its not secure :) they can just go to the url, Its the only way possible I can do this right now so.

Comment: Which name is your name?

Comment: Mr.EasyBB, thank you Explosion, I was waiting to see you haha. But runawayhorses and BL@DE can not see the button that I want them to

Comment: updated @thatidiotguy with the jsfiddle

Comment: what is up with the negative votes people? Don't just negative it, I did what you asked. I don't need to be banned over something silly because of the constant negatives on this one question HOLY MOLY PEOPLE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop shows or removes the `.nlgchat` element after EACH name in the loop. That means that if the first name isn't found in the list -- as is the case in your example -- the element is removed and can't be shown again.

To fix, use a Boolean value outside the loop, and show or remove the element AFTER the loop is completed:

```
    doshow = false;
    for (i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
        doshow = doshow || (nameslist.indexOf('||' + usernames[i]) > -1);
        // once it's true, it stays true
    }
    if (doshow) {
        $('.nlgchat').show();
    } else {
        $('.nlgchat').remove();
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/NR7RG/

By the way, unless `nameslist` is being used elsewhere in your code, you're better off replacing it with a simple array. There's always the possibility that some user will have `||` inside their username and mess up your code:

```
    var nameslist = [];
    $('ul li a.mainmenu').each(function(i) {
        var name = $(this).text().split(' ')[3];
        nameslist.push(name);
    });

    doshow = false;
    for (i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
        doshow = doshow || ($.inArray(usernames[i],nameslist) > -1);
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/NR7RG/3/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: Thank you @Blazemonger I like it. I'm going to try and see if it works for those users. Thanks again

Comment: That's the logical "OR" -- it returns TRUE if either argument is true.

Comment: this code actually is breaking my codes. I don't know what is wrong though

Comment: Use your JavaScript debugger (F12 on Windows, usually) to try and find what line is causing the problem. Mine works in the jsfiddle.

Comment: yeah thats what I don't understand now. I know the js works. I'm on mac

Comment: Check your browser's menus. View > Developer > Developer Tools or something like that.